# date command not resolving properly in bash alias

Tags: bash, alias, date, nano

I'm trying to set up a way for me to just type `newjournal`, and a new journal entry named `year-month-date-time.txt` is created in a `year` subdirectory in `~/documents/journals`.

I've got it set up as an alias using the following:

```
alias newjournal='nano /home/username/documents/journals/'$(date +%Y)'/'$(date +%F-%k%M).txt''
```

So the year subfolder resolves correctly, and seemingly so does the first half of the date command. Tried appending the alias with `sudo`, didn't help.

Issue: For some reason, when I do this command the time value (`%k`) resolves to a few minutes ago... or maybe the last time nano ran this filename, maybe it's called an old buffer?

**When I logoff it makes the correct file, then I save, wait a few minutes and try again, and it edits the old file instead of making a new one. Even if I remove the old file, it creates a new file with the old filename (incorrect time).**

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to explain. Here I create a newjournal, save in nano within a second or two of executing the command, print the correct date/time, list the file that was created. Note the incorrect filename time (1249, as apposed to 13:11):

[image: screenshot]

Anyways, it might be something simple, but I've tried different methods in the alias, such as putting double quotes around the whole thing and escaping properly, single quoting, escaping and spacing, etc.

Thanks for the read/help. Ubuntu 16.04 server.

EDIT: Here's the final alias that worked:

```
alias newjournal='nano /home/user/journals/"$(date +%Y)"/"$(date +%F-%H%M).txt"'
```

Needed to double quote the date commands inside the overall single-quoted alias.

Comment: Run `alias newjournal` and I think you'll see the issue.

Comment: so it's double quoting the values. I've changed the alias quoting to single quotes and it's resolved the quoting when running alias newjournal, but not the time issue. I'm still not understanding why it's not updating the time when I run the alias. Maybe it's so simple... I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the final alias.  I'm still struggling getting something similar working.

Comment: @JustinNoel Added the alias to the end of the original post. Had to double quote the commands that are resolved by bash inside a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `date` commands are evaluated **when you declare the alias**.

Here's an example alias `t`:

```
$ alias t="echo \"$(date +%k%M)\""
$ alias t
alias t='echo "1357"'
```

You can fix this by using single quotes:

```
$ alias t='echo "$(date +%k%M)"'
$ alias t
alias t='echo "$(date +%k%M)"'
```

For more info, see [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/4518341)

---

Or if the command doesn't need to be an alias, use a function instead:

```
$ function t { echo "$(date +%k%M)"; }
$ declare -f t
t () 
{ 
    echo "$(date +%k%M)"
}
```

Or a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$(date +%k%M)"
```

---

#### Update, per recent edit

```
$ alias t='echo '$(date +%k%M)''
$ alias t
alias t='echo 1400'
```

Think of that alias definition as three strings:

1. One single-quoted string: `'echo '`
2. One unquoted string: `$(date +%k%M)`
3. One single-quoted null string: `''`

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! I was close... just have been confused about the quoting process in alias. Had to double quote the commands inside single quoted alias, instead of single quote commands inside single quoted alias. Your answer and article were very helpful.

Comment: This answer is very informative , but I'm not finding it to actually be the answer to the original problem.  What is the final command to YMGenesis's question that actually solves the problem?

Comment: @Justin The question changed a bit, so that might be part of the confusion. Anyway the tl;dr of my answer is *quote the alias so it doesn't get evaluated*. LMK if that's not what you're looking for.