# Alias to go to newest folder in a folder

Tags: bash, alias

We have robot results created into separate folders in format of "result-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss" and I currently have this in my bash_aliases

```
alias res="VAR=$(ls --directory /path/to/results/res* | tail -n 1); cd $"
```

It works fine once.. then I have to reload my bashrc to make it work again. Tried baking the reload into a new alias but still had to use that 2-3 times before it switches to newer folder.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Double quotes allow the alias contents to be evaluated at definition time - use single quotes to postpone evaluation until runtime:

```
alias res='var=$(ls --directory /path/to/results/res* | tail -n 1); cd $var'
```

See also:

- [Command in .bash_profile returns outdated result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060878/command-in-bash-profile-returns-outdated-result?)
- [date command not resolving properly in bash alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965492/date-command-not-resolving-properly-in-bash-alias)

Answer (score 6):

The problem with using `ls` is that something has to parse the output of `ls`, which is broadly accepted to be a bad thing. You get weird edgecases with filenames that contain newlines and other oddities that `tail` might trip over.

You can do what you want with simple glob expansion:

```
for i in /path/to/res-*/; do :; done; cd "$i"
```

This is essentially just ticking through the list of things and doing nothing except assigning it to the variable `i`. When it's done looping, it just uses the last value for `i`. It's not very clever but it should offer acceptable performance up to a few million nodes.

And as the others have suggested, you can alias that in your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias res='for i in /path/to/res-*/; do :; done; cd "$i"'
```

Comment: Adding a slash to the pattern limits results to just directories: `res-*/`

Comment: Great point @glennjackman, thank you

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: This is a poor solution to the title of the OP, although it would work for the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use aliases for anything more complex than abbreviating the name of a command or passing default parameters to a command. Use a function instead. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches.

```
res () {
  local latest
  latest="$(ls --directory /path/to/results/res* | tail -n 1)" && cd "$latest"
}
```

- The `local` declaration keeps the variable local to the function, so it won't interfere with a variable with the same name defined outside the function.
- Using `&&` ensures that `cd` isn't executed if `ls` fails because there are no matching files.
- The `local` declaration and the assignment to `latest` are in separate instructions. Otherwise the status of `local latest="$(…)"` would be 0, even if the command inside `$(…)` failed.
- Always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions unless you know why it's ok to leave them off.

Your attempt didn't work because the command substitution in `VAR=$(…)` and the variable substitution in `cd $VAR` are evaluated when the alias is defined. If you use single quotes instead, the exact string inside the quotes is evaluated when you run the alias, which would work in this case. I don't recommend using an alias though, even if it can be made to work, because functions are a lot simpler to get right.

Comment: Shouldn't `ls` be avoided in scripts? maybe using `find` instead?

Comment: @Navaro `find` wouldn't help here. `ls` should be avoided in scripts because it can mangle file names. But this is for interactive use, so it's less important: in the few cases where this will break (such as a newline in a file name, which wouldn't fit the naming pattern assumed in this question), the user can handle the failure. And the focus of the question was on the alias, so I didn't change the `ls` part.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to read only one line, I suggest you use builtin `read`

```bsh
res(){
    read -r < <( \
    ls -r --quoting-style=shell-escape /a/b/c*); eval cd "$REPLY"
}
```

<sup>You can either put the function in .bashrc or .bash_aliases.</sup>